# The parameter is incorrect

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I try to add a service reference to my project in Visual Studio I keep getting the error " The parameter is incorrect" I know it's not the code because it doesn't happen on my coworkers computer. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio to see if the problem is with my installation. But that doesnt seem to fix it.

I am using visual Studio 2012.

Did anyone come across this issue before? Please help!

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem with a project that was copied out of ClearCase. the .csproj file still had the reference telling visual studio that its still under CC. I removed the following references and it worked.

```
<SccProjectName>Rational ClearCase</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>Rational ClearCase</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>Rational ClearCase</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>Rational ClearCase</SccProvider>
```

Comment: I had different values on these elements but removing these four lines solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after updating SQLite plugin for windows phone.
It seems like the sqlite-net-wp8 project (which is a wrapper to work with the plugin) had some import method from that plugin and when the version changed the wrapper didn't work anymore.

The solution was to downgrade the sqlite plugin to a version that is compatible with the wp8 wrapper.

**Edit:** The wrapper had an update so I've upgraded both the plugin and wrapper and now the issue is fixed.

If it shows any project in your solution with "(failed)" next to it's name try to remove it and re-add it to your solution and it will tell you what the issue exactly is.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Frisons answer - the issue works aswell the other way round:

If you *are* using ClearCase, make sure that the entries mentioned by Frison are available in your project file. I just had this case that one of the projects in my solution did not (however) had these entries and i got the very same error. Adding these lines fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error for WindowsPhone project, after make a clear manifest the error disappeared.